# Kendo tabstrip(index) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui

I've Two tabs, First tab where I've defined `class = "k-state-active"`. In 2nd tab, i've few `buttons` & `Grid`. Based on `button` click I need `Grid` (in the 2nd tab) to be populated (server side) after the postback. I've below `JQuery` to show 2nd tab after postback which is not working.

```
$(function () {
   $('Button').click(function () {
   var tabstrip = $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip().data("kendoTabStrip");​​
   tabstrip.select(1);
   });
});
```

With above code, I'm getting first tab instead of 2nd tab after button click. Please help.

Comment: have you tried `tabstrip.select(2);`?

Comment: it is still going to 1st tab

Comment: if you're doing a postback of the entire page, then of course it's going to select the first tab, as the entire page is refreshed. You will have to treat the page load after a postback separately, and set the active tab to the second tab right after constructing your tabstrip. If you'd provide a jsfiddle or more code it would be much easier to help :)

Comment: Another thing, before I add more code, when I use `alert(tabstrip.select().Index());` after `tabstrip.select(1)`, I get alert as "1" & if I use `tabstrip.select(2)`, I get alert as "-1"

Comment: then `select(1)` is the correct way, you're most likely having issues due to the postback (i.e. it selects the second tab then refreshes the entire page, thus losing the tab selection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove this part of the code `.kendoTabStrip()`

Thus it will become:

```
$(function () {
   $('Button').click(function () {
   var tabstrip = $("#tabstrip").data("kendoTabStrip");​​
   tabstrip.select(1);
   });
});
```